# How to change the data of a node in Linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

struct:

```
//linked list
struct list
{
  int32_t data;
  struct list *next;
};

struct list *head;
```

at first, initialize linked list (every node be 0):

```
void initLinkedList(int size)
{   
    head = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list)*size);
    struct list *current = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        (current+i)->data= 0;
    }
}
```

function:

```
void changeNode(int32_t element, int index)
{   
    struct list *current = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        current = current->next;
        
    } 

    current->data= element;
}
```

so basically, I want to create a linked list with `size` nodes, then change the data of the node through function.

But I'm getting Segmentation fault at this line in function:
`current->localVar = element;`

So, how can I change the data of a node without inserting a new one?

Comment: The problem is with your changeNode function, you haven't assign current->next to any pointer.

Comment: You might want to get in the habit of using `size_t` for indexes unless negative indexing is a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here `void initLinkedList(int size)` you aren't creating/initializing a linked list instead you are declaring an **array of type `struct list` dynamically with `size` no. of elements** and then you are initializing all of them with value `0`.

To initialize your `linked list` code this:

```
void initLinkedList(int size)
{
    if((head = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list)*size)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Unavailable.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct list *current = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        current->data = 0;
        if ((current->next = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list))) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory Unavailable.\n");
            exit(2);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = NULL;
}
```

Then to **`changeNode`**, code this:

```
void changeNode(int element, int index)
{
    struct list *current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while(count != index)
    {
        if(current->next)
            current = current->next;
        count++;
    }
    current->data = element;
}
```

Here I'm adding another function to print the `linked list`:

```
void print(struct list *head)
{
    if(head->next)
    {
        printf("%d", head->data);
        head = head->next;
        print(head);
    }
}
```

**`main()`:**

```
int main(void)
{
    initLinkedList(5);
    changeNode(5, 4);
    print(head);
    delete(head);
    printf("Memory freed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can see the **Sample Output:**

```
00005
Memory freed.
```

One more thing, if you are confused about this:

`if ((current->next = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list))) == NULL)`

I can help you. In the above line of code, we're allocating memory to `current->next` and checking if memory is allocated successfully or not.

Freeing the memory allocated to linked list using **`delete()`** function:

```
void delete( struct list *head )
{
  struct list *current = head;
  struct list *next = NULL;
  while(current != NULL)
  {
    next = current->next;
    free(current);
    current = next;
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I free `current->next = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list))`

Comment: Yes, that would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You must consider whether you have requested to change an index that doesn't exist in your list, but otherwise you are close. You are not iterating your `initLinkedList` in a traditional manner (you are treating the list like an array) As a side-note: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714).

Let's start with your `initLinkedList` function. You have declared `head` globally (assuming) and then go to fill your list with zeros. In doing so, you never initialize any of your `->next` pointers. You don't end up with a linked-list -- you have a block of allocated nodes.

You should iterate `current = current->next;` and set each `->next` pointer, not just use the offset `+i`. You are able to initialize your `data` like that due to allocating all nodes in a continual block -- but any node added later will not be contiguous in memory and none of your `->next` pointers are initialized.

Now on to your `changeNode` function. You must fix your `initLinkedList` to initialize the `->next` pointers. Then you need to change the return type from `void` to `struct list*` so you can return a pointer to the changed node on success or `NULL` on failure. Currently, you have no way of knowing if your change succeeded or failed.

Making the changes you could do:

```
struct list *changeNode (int32_t element, int index)
{
    struct list *current = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (!current->next) {
            fputs ("error: request exceeds no. of nodes in list.\n", stderr);
            return NULL;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->data = element;

    return current;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.